# Problem with QGIS 2.2 joins between shapefile and CSV

Tags: qgis, csv, attribute-joins

Didn't see question like this asked, so...

I've joined a CSV file to a shapefile and everything seems OK.  I've modified attribute form so that fields from joined CSV appears in there.

So far so good- it's there. But when I reopen the project and identify some feature, instead of joined fields there's `"Error:Field does not exist in datasource"` even though I see it when opening the attribute table.

If I open the layers properties and then press OK, the attributes are back in my form.

Is there any way to avoid this annoyance?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to add any additional data to the csv, you could save the shapefile layer as a new layer, this will fuse the data in the csv file to the shapefile and will be saved in the shapefiles .dbf file

Not sure why this problem would happen in the first place, unless there is some confusing information in the csv file.
Also check the Save paths in the project properties>General>General settings. Mine are usually on relative. Are all the shapefiles and csv files located in the same folder?